# How can i kill and restart a Python script at a fixed time?

Tags: linux

On a VPS, i have a Python script running 24/7. For various reasons I need that script to reboot every tot. hours, basically it just needs to restart every 2-3-4 hours. I might be able to find a solution to do that in code, but I would rather see if i can do that from Linux.

To start it, I use `nohup python3 myscript.py`. Is there any way to do that? Do i need an external dependency?

Comment: What does `tot. hours` mean? You can put in a script, call it `script &`, wait for some time, kill it and start it again in a loop.

Comment: I can't do it manually, it needs to do it by itself; so every 6 hours, for example, the process should be killed and restart instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run use `cron` to schedule the script every X hours. When the new instance starts, it

- locates the existing instance (checking `/var/run/{scriptname}.pid`)
- kills it if it exists
- write its own process id to `/var/run/{scriptname}.pid`
- continues until killed by next

Variants of `cron` may also let you start the script when the system boots.

A better solution is to [create/install your script as a systemd service](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6), and have it be [restarted periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055194/how-can-i-configure-a-systemd-service-to-restart-periodically).

Comment: This is the most reasonable way to go, thank you!